# How to get the IP address of an incoming data packet on a DGRAM socket in WinSock2?

Tags: c++, sockets, winsock2

I am doing some work with WinSock and servers, and I want to get the IP address of the client sending a packet of information to the server.I would prefer to use SOCK_DGRAM-style sockets, using the UDP protocol. Since I am not using sockets with listen(), accept(), and connect(), and therefore cannot use getpeername(), I would like to know how I can get this information. A short code snippet would be appreciated. Also, right now I am only communicating on the server on the LAN right now, but will eventually need to move farther out.

EDIT:
As far as code goes, I'm not sure what to put.

I have a socket sock_serv

it is initialized like so:

sock_serv = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);

I do some recv()ing later on, after setting a timeout. I have confirmed that the timeout works, and I can get data from recv but don't know how to get the sender.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `recvfrom()`. It has an output struct sockaddr parameter. See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740120(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: Thanks a lot, this should work. I have been stuck on this for a while.